# Distribute guides evenly in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, interface-design

I'm trying to make a color chart for someone that would be four thumbnails across and four thumbnails down. Now, this seems simple, but there is too much math and calculator work to try and get this to work. Ideally, I'd love to account some gutters/margins, but I just can't figure it out. I found this article from 2006 that seemed perfect, until I couldn't find the option listed there.

http://layersmagazine.com/quick-distribute-those-ruler-guides.html

**EXAMPLE (Not evenly distributed):**
[image]

Does anyone else know how to do this?

Comment: I'd cheat... do it in Illustrator or InDesign, export a JPG, bring the JPG into Photoshop, and use that as a template to drop your guides. Sometimes it's faster to fake it. :)

Comment: Interesting... so it's easier to do it in Illustrator? How do I do that?

Comment: By the way. In case you didn't notice, that method in your link is for indesign.

Comment: Draw your boxes in Illustrator and use the Align/Distribute tool to distribute them however you like. Export, import, trace.

Answer (score 5):

Hope this can help, i use this extension for photoshop and it works really great:

http://www.guideguide.me/

Comment: This is one of the best ones. I use it all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Go to settings => general => grids.

Choose how you want your grid to lay out (every 30%, every 100px, etc.)

Turn on snap to grid

Drag guides wherever you see fit.

Comment: In Photoshop 2021: Photoshop => Preferences => Guides, Grid & Slices

Answer (score 2):

Two ways, go to: View then select **New Guide Layout** and then add Columns and Rows as needed on the pop-up dialog.

Second option, you can follow this video for other options. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RY0dfjLUQHY

Answer (score 0):

Seems that just using this tool is the easiest. Photoshop will allow you to snap the guides to it pretty easily.

http://gridpak.com/